# How do I turn on Up Next on TV in tvOS 13's dock?

Tags: appletv, tv.app

I don’t like the new preview feature in tvOS 13. I want my Up Next view back for the TV app in the dock. How do I turn it back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tvOS 13.3 adds an option to change the mode on the shelf of the TV app. Go to Settings > App Settings > TV and click on Top Shelf to change it to “Up Next”.